# How to find the value of series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n \pi^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1}(2n+1)!}$

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \pi^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1}(2n+1)!} $$

Thanks to Wolfram Alpha, I know that the value is 1, but I have no clue how to get to that. Please help, I have been sitting on this for hours.

It looks like sinus or cosinus, so I could turn it into the form:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \cdot \dfrac{\pi^{2n} \cdot \pi}{2 \cdot 2^{2n} (2n+1) (2n)!}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \cdot \frac{\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!} \cdot \frac{\pi}{2^{2n+1} (2n+1)} $$

Now the first part of the equation looks like a $\cos(\pi)$, but what should I do with the second part? Something is telling me Cauchy product, but I'm not sure it that first here.

Another idea is of course

$$= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \cdot \frac{\pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \cdot \frac{1}{2^{2n+1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{2n+1}} \cdot \frac{\pi^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} $$

But yeah, I pretty much get stuck here, I feel like I'm missing some information, but I don't know what I should be looking for.

Comment: You may write the series as $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2n+1}. $$ Now try to compare this with the power series $$\sin x = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}. $$

Comment: Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

Write it as
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{(\frac{\pi}{2})^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=1$$
using the Maclaurin series for $\sin$.

Comment: Thanks a lot bunch as well!